# how to redirect to a page with jQuery/CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am trying this but have an jQuery Error

```
$(location).attr("href",'/imageblocks/'+$(el).attr('id')+'/edit/')
```

It works perfectly on JavaScript but trigger an jQuery error with CoffeScript, i guess it's the $(location) but can't find the correct word.

Answer (score 8):

This Javascript will do:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

In fact, this means is optimal because `replace()` does not put the previous page in the browser session history.

Hence, if the user clicks the back button, he/she will not fall into a cycle of page reloads.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use: window.location.href = your_url